# Specify method at as_view in Django urls. (GET, POST etc)

Tags: django, django-views

I have some classes with (APIView) and obviously I include them in my urls.py.
Question is, if there is a way, to specify method, when I use construction like that:

```
path('mods/mix', MixCUD.as_view()),
path('mods/mix/update/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view()),
path('mods/mix/delete/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view()),
```

Because, if I understand correctly, I can call delete method of a MixCUD from mods/mix/update/int:mixId address.

So I need something like that:

```
path('mods/mix', MixCUD.as_view([POST])),
path('mods/mix/update/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view([UPDATE])),
path('mods/mix/delete/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view([DELETE])),
```

I can't change them all to a single address, so I have to manage this somehow.

Comment: Probably you might need to use `ViewSet` instead of `APIView`

Comment: @NKSM I know, just been waiting if there's someone else gonna give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Passing extra options to view functions**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions)

```
path('mods/mix', MixCUD.as_view(), {"action": "POST"}),
path('mods/mix/update/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view(), {"action": "UPDATE"}),
path('mods/mix/delete/<int:mixId>', MixCUD.as_view(), {"action": "DELETE"}),
```

And then you can use `self.kwargs` in your view, output will be::

```
{"action": "POST"}
```